# Upload image flutter web with dio formdata Error: Unsupported operation: MultipartFile is only supported where dart:io is available

Tags: flutter, dart

#### I am trying using image_picker and dio packages to upload files as form data.

This is for flutter web and it seems MultipartFile.fromFile is not accepted.

What I tried is the following:

```
Future<T?> uploadHtml<T>(
    String url, {
      Map<String, dynamic>? queryParameters,
      required List<String> filePaths,
      Map<String, dynamic>? headers,
      bool showLoading = true,
      bool Function(ApiException)? onError,
    }) async {

  List<MultipartFile> files = [];
  for(String path in filePaths){
    String filename = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    var suffix = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
    if(suffix=='webp'){
      suffix = 'jpeg';
    }
    MultipartFile multipartFile = await MultipartFile.fromFile(
      path,
      filename:filename,
      contentType: MediaType.parse("image/$suffix"),
    );
    files.add(multipartFile);
  }
  FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({"files": files});
  return request(url,
      method: "POST",
      queryParameters: queryParameters,
      data: formData,
      headers: headers,
      onError: onError);
}
```